# Perl: For each key in hash printing the first value...in the next loop the second and so on

Tags: perl, transpose

So,

I feed  a lot of .txt files data with biological sequences into my @col array... I need the frequence of occurences of the several letters (A,C,G,T) at each position...everything is fine...it works but i want to transpose the output like that...

the output is:

A 1.112 1.124 1.258

C 1.154 1.122 1.587

G 1.158 1.454 1.478

T 1.154 1.125 1.478

But I want to transpose that...I mean the rows into columns...like

A  C     G     T

1.112 1.154 1.154  1.154

and so on

The code:

```
@col = {GTGTCCATTAGAGGGCGCCA GCAGCCTCCTGAGGACGCCA GAGACCTCAAGGGGCCACTA GGGGCCACTAGGGGGCTCGA ATGGCCACAAGAGGGCGTCA CTGCCCGCCCGGCGGCGCCG GCGGGCAGCAGGGGGAGCCG ATCACCACCAGGTGGCGCCG AAGGACACTAGGTGGAGCCA TCGGCCGGCAGAGGGCGCTG ATGACCGCCAGGGGTCGCTC ACCACCAGCAGGGGGCACCT GCAGCCCGTGGGGGGCGCCG GTGGGCGGCAGGGGGCGCTG CCAGCCTCTAGGGGCCACTG TTGACCACCAGATGGTGGTA CCTGCCGAAAGGGGGCAGTG and so on }

foreach my $row(@col)
  {       
   ++$pwm{ substr $row, $_, 1 }[ $_ ] for 0 .. length( $row ) -1;  #holt die Teilstrings aus der Zeile, sprich Pos 1, Pos2....
  }
  @col=();  # benoetige leeres array fuer oben
  @$_ = map{ $_ ? ($_/$row_counter)+1 : 1 } @$_ for values %pwm;

 print "$_ @{ $pwm{$_}}\n" for sort keys %pwm;
```

Comment: Where's the data? Please read [how to create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Your code is very dense and I for one am having trouble understanding it. You really should avoid using `map`, a conditional expression, a statement modifier, and the `$_` variable all in the same statement. But if you at least add enough to your program so that we can reproduce your output then I am sure you you will soon get a solution

Comment: Thank you, but there is still something missing. What is `$row_counter`?

Comment: **$row_counter** counts the rows... so I get the frequence....

Answer (score 3):

This appears to do what you need, although I am surprised that you want your frequencies to vary from 1 to 2 rather than from 0 to 1

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my @col = qw/
    GTGTCCATTAGAGGGCGCCA
    GCAGCCTCCTGAGGACGCCA
    GAGACCTCAAGGGGCCACTA
    GGGGCCACTAGGGGGCTCGA
    ATGGCCACAAGAGGGCGTCA
    CTGCCCGCCCGGCGGCGCCG
    GCGGGCAGCAGGGGGAGCCG
    ATCACCACCAGGTGGCGCCG
    AAGGACACTAGGTGGAGCCA
    TCGGCCGGCAGAGGGCGCTG
    ATGACCGCCAGGGGTCGCTC
    ACCACCAGCAGGGGGCACCT
    GCAGCCCGTGGGGGGCGCCG
    GTGGGCGGCAGGGGGCGCTG
    CCAGCCTCTAGGGGCCACTG
    TTGACCACCAGATGGTGGTA
    CCTGCCGAAAGGGGGCAGTG
/;

my %pwm;

for ( @col ) {

    my @row = split //;  #/

    for my $i ( 0 .. $#row ) {
        my $k = $row[$i];
        ++$pwm{$k}[$i];
    }
}

for my $counts ( values %pwm ) {
    for my $count ( @$counts ) {
        $count = ( $count // 0) / @col + 1;
    }
}

my @keys = sort keys %pwm;

my $fmt = '%-5s ' x @keys . "\n";
printf $fmt, @keys;

$fmt = '%.3f ' x @keys . "\n";

for my $i ( 0 .. @col ) {
    printf $fmt, map { $pwm{$_}[$i] } @keys;
}
```

#### output

```
A     C     G     T     
1.294 1.176 1.412 1.118 
1.118 1.412 1.059 1.412 
1.176 1.118 1.647 1.059 
1.294 1.059 1.588 1.059 
1.059 1.824 1.118 1.000 
1.000 2.000 1.000 1.000 
1.471 1.059 1.294 1.176 
1.059 1.588 1.294 1.059 
1.176 1.529 1.000 1.294 
1.824 1.059 1.059 1.059 
1.000 1.000 2.000 1.000 
1.294 1.000 1.706 1.000 
1.000 1.059 1.765 1.176 
1.000 1.000 2.000 1.000 
1.059 1.118 1.765 1.059 
1.118 1.824 1.000 1.059 
1.235 1.000 1.706 1.059 
1.000 1.824 1.118 1.059
```